# correct format of URL rewrite in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm asking about htaccess url rewrite ( `mod_rewrite` )

actually i want to change below URL

`http://localhost/project/cms/edit_item.php?id=MYc=` ( actually this is base 64 encoded)

to

```
http://localhost/project/cms/edit_item.php/id/MYc=
```

i do it like this on *.htaccess* file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\-_0-9A-Za-z]+)$  edit_item.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and save this on project folder
but URL didn't modified

please suggest me how to do it

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: my .htaccess file is at htdocs/project/cms/ folder
and my all other php files are also on same (htdocs/project/cms/)folder

Comment: So the `cms` part is added afterwards?

Comment: You don't even need an .htaccess file if you want the `.php` to stay there. There's just one setting to be set correctly in Apache. Let me go look it up.

Comment: all files are inside cms folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.+)
RewriteRule (edit_item.php) $1/id/%1?
```

Comment: not working dear? does i need to restart xampp and logout from site then it"ll be effective

Comment: It should not. I omitted the `RewriteEngine on` line there. Do you have it in place in the file before those lines?

Comment: If you want the browser to show the rewritten URL then you need to add the `[R]` flag.

Comment: when i use [R]
It become
`http://localhost/D:/xampp/htdocs/project/cms/edit_item.php/id/MTc4`

Comment: ... What? That doesn't even make any sense. What version of httpd is this?

Comment: in don't know the version dear?
it's XAMPP for Windows Version 1.7.1 !